# R shiny iframe does not connect to HTTPS Flask app

Tags: r, flask, iframe, https, shiny

I am trying to display a python `flask` app in an `R shiny iframe`.

For a normal http protocol, this is working fine. However, once I change it to an https protocol it does not connect although I can display the https flask app in my browser without a problem. Displaying public https websites within the iframe is not a problem either

My flask code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/data", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def home():
    return render_template('index.html')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True, host='localhost', port=5000, ssl_context=('cert.pem', 'key.pem'))
```

My R shiny code:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fillPage(
    htmlOutput("frame")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$frame <- renderUI({
    tags$iframe(src="https://localhost:5000/data", style='width:100vw;height:100vh;')
    # tags$iframe(src="https://www.bbc.co.uk/sport", style='width:100vw;height:100vh;')
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Check that your flask app and rshiny app are both https